# Variable inclause is not working for the PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this PL/SQL piece of code RESTALLSEQUENCENUMBERLIST contains value '2,3,4' which i am converting this into '2','3','4' for the in clause in the third line by the second statement. But my update query is giving me invalid number. Can anybody help with this

```
restAllSequenceNumberInList varchar2(100);

SELECT 
'''' || REPLACE( RESTALLSEQUENCENUMBERLIST, ',', ''',''' ) || '''' 
into restAllSequenceNumberInList FROM DUAL;

UPDATE THIRD_PARTY_LOOKUP 
SET ADDRESS_ID = firstSequenceNumber 
WHERE ADDRESS_ID in  (RESTALLSEQUENCENUMBERINLIST);
```

Comment: You would have to make your string part of a [Dynamic SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm) query that you construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `in` clause does not take a string argument that represents multiple values.  It is as simple as that.  If you pass a single string to `in` it behaves the same as `=`.

You can do what you want using `like`:

```
UPDATE THIRD_PARTY_LOOKUP 
    SET ADDRESS_ID = firstSequenceNumber 
    WHERE ','||ADDRESS_ID||',' LIKE '%,' || RESTALLSEQUENCENUMBERLIST  || '%,';
```

However, instead of storing lists in a string, why not store them in a temporary table?  After all, tables are the SQL construct designed explicitly for storing lists of things.

Comment: Thanks.. When i run the below query separately, it runs successfully  
UPDATE THIRD_PARTY_LOOKUP SET ADDRESS_ID = firstSequenceNumber 
WHERE ADDRESS_ID in  ('1','2','3');
So what is the difference when i use a variable.

Comment: @JManish . . . When you use a variable, it is doing `where addressid = "'1','2','3'"`, an unlikely value at best and impossible if `addressid` is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass comma separated list in a variable and assume SQL to treat them as separate values, try this

```
--replace with " not '
SELECT 
REPLACE '''' ||  REPLACE( RESTALLSEQUENCENUMBERLIST, ',', '","' ) || '''' 
into restAllSequenceNumberInList FROM DUAL;

--use xml to split them into rows
UPDATE THIRD_PARTY_LOOKUP 
SET ADDRESS_ID = firstSequenceNumber 
WHERE ADDRESS_ID in 
(SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(COLUMN_VALUE,'text()') VALS 
 FROM XMLTABLE(restAllSequenceNumberInList) )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using one single string containing the list. You need a list generated from splitting the string using one way or another. Unfortunately there exists no "easy" split function. Several methods exist.